# Taking a limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $ \left(a_n \left(\varepsilon \right) \right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence which depends on $\varepsilon$.

I want to calculate the limit
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow \alpha } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\varepsilon \right). $$

So is it generally true that

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow \alpha } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\varepsilon \right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow \alpha }  a_n \left(\varepsilon \right)  \right)$$
and how could I justify it? I think the rule would be obvious if I summed finitely many members, but I'm not so sure about the infinite series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality is not true in general.

A sufficient condition is given by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem applied to discrete measure.

It is sufficient to have $\vert a_n(\epsilon) \vert \le b_n$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ where $\sum b_n$ converges.

In that case

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow \alpha } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \left(\varepsilon \right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow \alpha }  a_n \left(\varepsilon \right)  \right)$$

Answer (score 4):

No, that doesn't hold. Not even if you require that each of your $a_n$ functions is continuous at $\alpha$.

For a counterexample, consider
$$ a_n(\varepsilon) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } \frac{1}{n+1} < |\varepsilon-\alpha| \le \frac1n \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(\varepsilon) = 1$ whenever $0<|\varepsilon-\alpha|\le 1$, but $\lim_{\varepsilon\to\alpha} a_n(\varepsilon) = 0$ for all $n$.